# Autofilling data on spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am new to this.  I apologize if this question has been answered.  I want to have my invoicing worksheet autofill from a financial setup worksheet (FSW) that my project managers use.  I want to take data from the FSW that looks like this

[image]

and have it autofill on my invoicing worksheet looking like this

[image]

I do not want the rows on the FSW with no monetary value to autofill, and want the rows with a monetary value to autofill with no empty rows in between.  I hope this makes sense and someone can guide me to this solution.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is probably with a pivot table. Make sure your data has headers. It is easiest if you put it into a table.

Select your data, click Insert > Pivot table. Then drag the Task into the Rows area and the Cost into the Values area of the pivot table. Right click a task in the pivot table an set a Value Filter to show only items greater than 0.

[image]